# How to scroll the android recyclerView on the whole and not based on the focus of the elements?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView for android TV that has a FAQ type of screen i.e one question and one answer and I am using adapter to feed data into it.

RecyclerView Layout-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
android:scrollbarSize="5px"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="150px">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Elements Layout-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionviewelement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:textColor="@color/color_question"
    android:textSize="@dimen/settings_faq_question_font_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answerviewelement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13px"
    android:textColor="@color/color_answer"
    android:textSize="@dimen/settings_faq_answer_font_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now suppose I have 28 pairs of questions and answers on the whole in the recyclerView. On the first load of the screen I have 5 pairs of questions and answers in front of me. Now to scroll up, when I press the down Key of the remote, it takes 4 key presses before the screen starts scrolling (since the focus shifts 5 times through individual QnAs and then to the bottom of the screen to scroll up).

How can I resolve this issue, such that on the first down key press, the view scrolls up.

Keeping in mind that the content is dynamic, I may have 2 pairs of QnAs on the screen or 7 pairs of QnAs on the screen, so programmatically

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(5)
```

on the creation of the view is not reliable everytime.

Any resolution is appreciated.

Comment: you can create row with 5 question answer and then scroll it once.

Comment: recyclerView can animate like view pager. if you use that functionality . then at first 5 question answer ,, that are in your row_layout are appeared,. when you scroll it once,. it will show nect 5 question answers

Comment: Using 5 QnAs at once is not recommended as the structure needs to be 1 QnA and then bind it according to the data in the Adapter. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try put in your recyclerview adapter

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
```

and setHasStableIds(true); before you populate data or receive your list (before your setData(List<> some) or in the constructor of the adapter). After that try with your `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(5)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. However this did not work, instead, my data got jumbled up every time on scrolling from top to bottom and vice versa.

Comment: Did you use an LinearLayoutManager in your adapter? because you can try to move with this linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(5);

Comment: Yes, I did use the same.
But as I mentioned in the question, the bottom of the screen could also be the 7th question or the 3rd question according to the dynamic content, so recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(5) will not work in that case every time.

Comment: But i suggest use with the linearlayoutmanager not with recyclerview like you use. Do you try this too?

Comment: My problem was solved by using a scrollview since I did not need the children to be focusable. Did not find the answer to the main question though.